# Make multiple buttons smooth scroll to top if pressed on

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

The following code creates buttons (dynamically) that if pressed go paint red some specific parts of a table that is on top of the page (irrelevant). These buttons are on the bottom of the table and I want it to scroll to the top whenever I press any of the buttons (in order to show the table). Also, if possible, I would like to not fill my URL with anything like # or #top.

```
   foreach ($simera as $row) {
        echo '<div class="row btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="active_class(\'' . $row->aith . '\')">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="width: 230px">' . $row->t . '(' . $row->tp . ')</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >' . $row->arxi . '</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >' . $row->telos . '</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >' . $row->aith . '</div>
            </div>';
    }
```

The `$row->x` parts should be irrelevant as they have to do with what the buttons have written on them.

I thought about having another script like `totop()` that would scroll to the top with the onclick but I cant seem to find how to make that work on all the buttons and even when I was close it still added `#`s to the URL (which I prefere to not have to)

PS: I dont know how to apply jQuery, so if the solutions needs jQuery please also tell me how it's applied on the code (ex: If I need something in the header or a specific id somewhere like an anchor or anything)...

thnx in advance :)

html output per button:

```
<div class="row btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="active_class('B105')">
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="width: 230px">History(Ε)</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >13:00:00</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >15:00:00</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >B105</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What's the output HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The following code (jQuery) will animate scrolling to the top of the page whenever you click on an element with the class `btn`, even if more are added with JS without refreshing:

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on("click",".btn",function(){
    $("body").animate({
      scrollTop:0
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried to make this work but it doesnt seem to do so... just to be sure: I added this to the header with `<script>` in front and `</script>` behind and added a link to enable JQuery in my site. If thats what I should do, then it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Every single block needs to have it's own ID

```
<div id="block1"></div>
```

and button has to have anchor with reference to that ID

```
<a href="#block1">Block 1</a>
```

Then just google for smooth scroll library which handle the rest or the usage should be super-easy

For example this one: http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/

Comment: does this work even though im not using href, but Im using button presses? I mean, wont that make all my buttons "links" that will link to the top?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the below code to **delegate events** to the dynamically generated elements:

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").on("click", "a[href^=#]", function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
      <li><a href="#Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
      <li><a href="#First">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Second">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Third">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Fourth">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Fifth">Item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Sixth">Item 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Seventh">Item 7</a></li>
    </ol>
    <h1 id="Welcome">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus earum perferendis asperiores deserunt, expedita inventore architecto ipsum blanditiis possimus fuga harum esse nulla. Nemo nihil beatae repellat totam deleniti. Quod!</p>
    <h2 id="First">First</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed possimus aliquid, asperiores ratione ab natus eos iusto, deleniti nemo ut consectetur tempora aspernatur. Impedit quibusdam, omnis doloremque quis et numquam!</p>
    <h2 id="Second">Second</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed possimus aliquid, asperiores ratione ab natus eos iusto, deleniti nemo ut consectetur tempora aspernatur. Impedit quibusdam, omnis doloremque quis et numquam!</p>
    <h2 id="Third">Third</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus nemo quo nisi rem nostrum similique, blanditiis quod cupiditate expedita aut. Nisi quibusdam, enim qui doloribus similique ullam impedit esse quidem?</p>
    <h2 id="Fourth">Fourth</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa sit commodi illo eos vel facere cumque aperiam, provident dolorum assumenda quidem vero ad qui harum voluptatum quos enim placeat quae!</p>
    <h2 id="Fifth">Fifth</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, adipisci molestiae dicta ad cum id debitis eos nihil reprehenderit beatae, numquam laboriosam, dolorum quis odio optio! Delectus illum, nemo suscipit!</p>
    <h2 id="Sixth">Sixth</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere nemo voluptates numquam accusamus optio, voluptatum amet, aliquam eveniet repudiandae atque voluptate ad commodi ducimus impedit ut dolorem iste libero.</p>
    <h2 id="Seventh">Seventh</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet vel ea quo assumenda quam commodi, libero, aliquid praesentium illum nulla, consectetur itaque minus optio quae! Maxime consectetur a modi ad.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

added this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

then changed this:

```
<div class="row btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="active_class('B105')">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="width: 230px">History(Ε)</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >13:00:00</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >15:00:00</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >B105</div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<a class="row btn btn-default btn-block scroll" href="#top" onclick="active_class('B105')">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="width: 230px">History(Ε)</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >13:00:00</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >15:00:00</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 70px" >B105</div>
</a>
```

and then I changed the `id` of my most top element to `id="top"`

the "not showing the #" that I wanted is in the JQuery part.

Thnx for the help you guys provided that helped me find the answer little by little. :)